# Sum of Permutations from 0 to n

Tags: summation, permutations

In a question I asked on algorithms with time complexity of $f(x) = n^n$ I was told that enumerating the number of strings that can be formed from a string of length $n$ qualifies.

I.e the sum of all permutations of $n$ from $n$ to $0$ is $n^n$

$\sum ^n_{i=0} nPi$ $= n^n$

Can I please see an easy to understand derivation of that formula.

**EDIT**
The above identity is wrong. I just tested it. Can I get a derivation of the formula for the sum of permutations.

Comment: What are you really asking? Do you want to know why it takes $n^n$ to compute all strings with length $n $, if you can use $n $ different characters?

Comment: I was told the number of strings that can be formed from a string of length 'n' is $n^n$.

Comment: I want to know why that is true. A derivation of the formula

Comment: What is "form" a string? Imagine the string is "abcd". How can you form different strings with it?

Comment: From string "abc": "a", "b", "c", "ab", "ac", "ba", "bc", "ca", "cb", "abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba". That's what I mean.

Comment: I think this is the answer of how many n digit strings you can form by using n chars (should be distinct).  Each position has n choices, so n^n. For example using "ab", you have aa, ab, ba, bb.

Comment: Oh. Yh, I realised it doesn't give the number of how many different strings can be formed from an n character string without repetition of any character in each string. That's what I was asking.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose you have $n$ distinct elements. Then the number of strings that can be formed of length $1$ to $n$ with distinct elements is

$$
f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
n\\
k
\end{array}\right)
k!
=
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{(n - k)!}
=
n!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k!}
$$

By Taylor's theorem we have that

$$
e = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!} + \frac{e^\xi}{(n+1)!}
$$

for some $\xi\in(0,1)$. Multiplying through by $n!$ we arrive at

$$
n!e = n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!} + \frac{e^\xi}{n+1} = f(n) + 1 + \frac{e^\xi}{n+1} 
$$

Since $e^\xi$ is an increasing function of $\xi$ we obtain

$$
\frac{1}{n+1} \leq en! - 1 - f(n) \leq \frac{e}{n+1}
$$

for all integers $n \geq 1$. Since $f(n)$ is an integer it follows that

$$
f(n) = \lfloor en! - 1\rfloor
$$

for all integers $n \geq 1$.

Comment: I am not really sure exactly how the Taytor's theorem is applied in the above derivation. Another reference I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161314/what-is-the-sum-of-following-permutation-series-np0-np1-np2-cdots-npn/161317#161317). Can I assume that since these are not closed form solutions both expression are correct ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to describe in more detail how Taylor's theorem is applied. In the reference you found, $S(n) = f(n) + 1$, so the expressions are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

This is something different.

with the example of 3 letters: a,b,c allowing "aab" it is rather
3^{0}+3^{1}\ +3^{2}+3^{3}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).