# Expected length of a string when all permutations are possible

Tags: probability, permutations, expected-value

Given n distinct objects, a set of all possible permutations of length 1-n are created. Then one of these permutations is chosen. I am trying to find out the expected length of this choice.

This is what I have currently:
From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019675/sum-of-permutations-from-0-to-n), I am assuming that the sum of all permutations is $\lfloor en! - 1 \rfloor$.
When $p(i)$ is the probability of an arrangement having a length $i$ the expected length of the choice is

$$ E(i) = \sum_{i=1}^n i * p(l_I) $$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^n i * \frac{P(n,i)}{\lfloor en! - 1 \rfloor} $$

My utimate objective is to create a plot of this expected value with varying parameter values. This ugly equation makes it very difficult. Am I doing this wrong ? Is there is better way to calculate this ?

Comment: Have you tried imitating the calculation at the linked question?  It's very similar.

Comment: In the linked question, I understand the first part of the derivation. But I am afraid that I am quite clueless about how the Taylor's theorem is applied to get the final expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$f(n)=n!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{k!}$$  It is proved in the answer you linked that $$f(n)=\lfloor en!-1\rfloor$$  We want to compute
$$\begin{align}
g(n)&=\sum_{k=1}^nk\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\\
&=n!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{k!}\\
&=n\cdot n!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{k!}-n!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{(k-1)!}\\
&=nf(n)-n(n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac1{k!}\\
&=nf(n)-nf(n-1)\\
&=n\left(\lfloor en!-1\rfloor-\lfloor e(n-1)!-1\rfloor\right)
\end{align}$$

Dividing by $\lfloor en!-1\rfloor$ gives $$n-n\frac{\lfloor e(n-1)!-1\rfloor}{\lfloor en!-1\rfloor}\approx n-1$$ as the expected value.

Comment: Thanks. For future reference a better explanation of F(n) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161314/what-is-the-sum-of-following-permutation-series-np0-np1-np2-cdots-npn/161317#161317)

Comment: @kgkmeekg Another explanation, anyway.  Personally, I like the first one better, but that's a matter of personal taste, I think.

Comment: @saulpatz Unlike the second link, the first one contains a step jump which I am not really able to grasp. But I can see that regardless of that both expressions apply to your solution above.